# Apache 2 html auto formatter?

Tags: perl, printing, apache2

Using perl 5.14 on Ubuntu 12.0.4 with Apache 2

In some way or another, when looking to the source in the webbrowser, my printed source is not matching. Some html formatter is executed, I want to turn it off.

Before I was using perl 5.6 with Apache and this issue did not occur.

Even is Html is not correctly formatted, it should not remove code in this way.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

print "Content-type:text/html\n\n";

print<<EOF;
<table>
<tr><td><i>Search for</i></td><td><i>Search in ...</i></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td valign="top">
<form action="$ENV{'SCRIPT_NAME'}" method="get">
<input type="text" class="formtext" id="txt2" autocomplete="off" name="find" size="53" maxlength="40" onkeyup="showResult2(this.value)" value="$QUERY{'find'}"><br><div id="livesearch2"></div>
<br>Option: <input type="checkbox" class="formtext" name="exact" $exactsel value="1"> Search Exact
</td><td valign="top">
<SELECT name="type" class="formtext"><OPTION $seltitle value="title">Titles<OPTION value="composer">Composers<OPTION value="track">Tracks<OPTION $selshop value="shop">Shopping</SELECT>
</td><td valign="top">
<INPUT type="hidden" name ="lang" value="en">
<INPUT type="submit" class="button" value="Search">
Here should be closing form tag, view source code, its has been removed? </form>
</td></tr></table>
EOF
```

Now the output in the web is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html><body><table>
<tr><td><i>Search for</i></td><td><i>Search in ...</i></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td valign="top">
<form action="/test.cgi" method="get">
<input type="text" class="formtext" id="txt2" autocomplete="off" name="find" size="53" maxlength="40" onkeyup="showResult2(this.value)" value="" /><br /><div id="livesearch2"></div>
<br />Option: <input type="checkbox" class="formtext" name="exact" value="1" /> Search Exact
</form></td><td valign="top">
<select name="type" class="formtext"><option value="title">Titles</option><option value="composer">Composers</option><option value="track">Tracks</option><option value="shop">Shopping</option></select>
</td><td valign="top">
<input type="hidden" name="lang" value="en" />
<input type="submit" class="button" value="Search" />
Here should be closing form tag, view source code, its has been removed? 
</td></tr></table></body></html>
```

Html code is added and the `</form>` is gone and that is giving me issues. It is not browser related, all show the same. In the command line, the script print is correctly.

Is this an Apache2 setting or something else? Where/How can I change it?

Comment: What's wrong with it. There are the required `<html>` etc tags added around it and the `${}` thing got filled in as expected. I see the 'form' tag.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply!This script worked before, it is an extract from a bigger file, do not worry about the variables. Just it is when I changed servers that I believe some apache setting is completing my code. When run in the command line, all shows correctly. When viewed in the web, it has been reformatted. And i am not calling a mod or anything else ...

Comment: Oh. I see. It moved the 'form' closing tag from where it was to where it legally should be. Move the opening 'form' tag above the 'table' tag to make it legal. It could be the browser depending on how you are viewing it.

Comment: Ok agree, but i have too many of these pages as legacy, it is too much work to change it. I just want to turn this corrector off somehwere (as on on older system, the corrections did not happen). To be sure it is not the browser, I did a wget of the same file on command line and indeed, the print content is different than the output directly from the command line, including added html tags, and removal of my </form>

Answer (score 0):

Change it to look like this so the tags are properly nested:

```
<form action="$ENV{'SCRIPT_NAME'}" method="get">
<table>
<tr>
  <td><i>Search for</i></td><td><i>Search in ...</i></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td valign="top">
    <input type="text" class="formtext" id="txt2" autocomplete="off" name="find" size="53" maxlength="40" onkeyup="showResult2(this.value)" value="$QUERY{'find'}"><br>
    <div id="livesearch2"></div>
    <br>Option: <input type="checkbox" class="formtext" name="exact" $exactsel value="1"> Search Exact
  </td>
  <td valign="top">
    <SELECT name="type" class="formtext"><OPTION $seltitle value="title">Titles<OPTION value="composer">Composers<OPTION value="track">Tracks<OPTION $selshop value="shop">Shopping</SELECT>
  </td>
  <td valign="top">
    <INPUT type="hidden" name ="lang" value="en">
    <INPUT type="submit" class="button" value="Search">
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
Here should be closing form tag, view source code, its has been removed? 
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks!! This works. But why would apache 2 (i think it is apache) automatically change a print output from my wrong formatted script? I am looking for a way to turn that feature off, I am not an apache expert.

Comment: I would suspect something in perl but anything between your code generation and the outgoing network connection could be doing it. Actually, it could be the browser reformatting it. Did you try several browsers? IE. Firefox. Chrome. Safari. Opera.

Comment: I found a quick work around, when using print "Content-type:text\n\n"; instead of print "Content-type:text/html\n\n"; there is no html correction done anymore. Just wondering I hope it does not have any header malfunctions?

Comment: This may not display correctly in some browsers. Some will try to display the text of the HTML itself.

Comment: That`s right, better be safe. I hope someone is reading this and knows how to change the behaviour of html re-formatting/completing when using print "Content-type:text/html\n\n"; in

Comment: You may be able to have Apache log what it gets from Perl. If its changed in that log, Perl is doing it. Be sure to check the browser thing too.

Comment: FOUND!!! There was a proxy server before I went on the internet with in the proxy settings this enabled: SetOutputFilter proxy-html; commented it out and the content is delivered without reformatting!